# Can I use Amazon's DNS servers for my mail server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

We have a domain mydomain.com, which we have registered with a UK registrar.  We are using Amazon's Route53, and this domain has been added in Route53 and is using the name servers as follows;

```
ns-558.awsdns-05.net
ns-1755.awsdns-27.co.uk
ns-466.awsdns-58.com
ns-1343.awsdns-39.org
```

I've added the relevant A records for www etc to point our elastic IP to this domain.

We are also running MailEnable on this EC2 server (running Windows 2012).  The MailEnable server is asking for me to enter DNS addresses ([Check and configure DNS settings](https://www.mailenable.com/documentation/6.0/Enterprise/Check%20and%20configure%20DNS%20settings.html)), I assume it will use when sending email.

My question is what DNS addresses / servers can I use ?  Can I use

```
ns-558.awsdns-05.net
ns-1755.awsdns-27.co.uk
ns-466.awsdns-58.com
ns-1343.awsdns-39.org
```

You can see the DNS address(es) in the screen shot below.

[image: DNS Address]

Comment: Are you using MailEnable for outbound mail only?

Comment: No, incoming mail only.  Outbound mail is forwarded using a smart host to another company offering a managed mail service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use those Amazon servers because they're authoritative-only (they'll only tell you about domains they know about, instead of acting as a recursive proxy). You can use Google's public DNS servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for that field.

(original answer below)

You need to create an A record that points at the elastic IP assigned to your mail server (for example, `mail.yoursite.com` points at 1.2.3.4). Then, you'd create an MX record for `yoursite.com` that points at `mail.yoursite.com`. Finally, I believe you would give MailEnable `mail.yoursite.com`, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: If you look at the screen shot in the Url https://www.mailenable.com/documentation/8.0/Standard/webframe.html#SMTP_props_-_General.html, you can see what I'm talking about

Comment: Thank you for adding a screenshot, and sorry for totally misinterpreting your question. I edited my answer.

Comment: Not saying [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) is a bad option, but [there is an alternative now](https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-1111/), Cloudflare's [1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, there is a point to use another free DNS. It hosts by CloudFlare (CF).

It validates DNSSEC and supports DoH, DoT, and IPv6.

Primary DNS IPv4, Secondary DNS IPv4, filtering:

1. 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1,  -
2. 1.1.1.2, 1.0.0.2, no malware.
3. 1.1.1.3, 1.0.0.3, no malware or adult content.